# How to get the list of apache modules enabled with php

Tags: php, apache

I have tried this

```
<?php

print_r(apache_get_modules());

?>
```

and got this

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_get_modules() in
```

Why the error for built in function and how to get list of modules

Comment: You are running php as apache module?

Comment: @King:Oh it is installed as CGI. Do you know how to check if mod_rewrite is enabled with CGI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/function.apache-get-modules.php) contains details about the PHP and Apache version that support `apache_get_modules()`.

You must be running PHP >= 4.3.2 and using Apache 2 handler API, or PHP >= 5.0 and Apache 1 or Apache 2 filter API.

Comment: and how to check if the mod_rewrite is enabled with CGI?

Comment: @Daric  Check my answer below to Check whether mod_rewrite is enabled under CGI or not