# .htaccess RewriteEngine won't handlle with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).cms$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

and in index.php it says i have an error in line 33

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules() in
>   /home1/linkele/public_html/badel.co/index.php on line 33

index.php

```
$_DATA['pages'][$key]['link'] = (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) 
                ? dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .'/'. $row['slug'] . '.cms' // Match it with the .htaccess file
                : 'index.php?p=' . $row['slug'];
```

note : it works fine on xampp and wamp server but didn't on my cpanel server when I uploaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of apache modules enabled with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547859/how-to-get-the-list-of-apache-modules-enabled-with-php)

Comment: idk the version running on hostgator

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` in a php page, it'll show you a lot of details

Comment: says : PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: In the same page, see whether the apache handler is active or not